# Connect dumb lamp to Hue/Homekit without switch

Tags: philips-hue, apple-homekit

I would like to connect a dumb lamp to my Hue/Homekit setup.

The lamp is powered by G9 LEDs and, as far as I know, there are no G9 smart bulbs.
I am also unable to exchange the physical wall switches.

I tried finding a smart component that could be injected between ceiling outlet and lamp, but couldn't find anything.

Does such a component exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are products like the [Sonoff](https://sonoff.itead.cc/en/) range that when flashed with the [Tasmota](https://github.com/arendst/Sonoff-Tasmota) firmware can emulate a Hue Bridge which might work, but this [issue](https://github.com/arendst/Sonoff-Tasmota/issues/3876) implies native HomeKit support is unlikely.

But once you have the controllable device other tools like Home Assistant might allow you to add HomeKit support.